# Replace variables programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like below

```
str = "http://{ server }:{ port }/images/{ server }/index.html"
```

The above string could have any number of variables and also one variable could be repeated in the same string as shown in the string.

Additionally, I have an input (dictionary) something like this:

```
dict = {"server": "xtz", "port": 8080}
```

How do I programmatically replace the variables with the values from the given dictionary.

I am hoping to write a function to do that.

Comment: What is the source of this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not for the spaces, you could be really concise using just [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Because of them you will need some preprocessing:

```
s = "http://{ server }:{ port }/images/{ server }/index.html"
d = {"server": "xtz", "port": 8080}

s = s.replace("{ ", "{").replace(" }", "}")

s = s.format(**d)
```

Comment: Why not just remove all the spaces? `s.replace(' ', '')`? A bit simpler.

Comment: Because spaces outside the `"{}"` might be actually part of the string.

Comment: I have never seen a URL containing any spaces

Comment: The OP did not restrict his question to URLS.

Answer (score 7):

[`str.format_map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) to the rescue!

```
>>> data = {"server": "xtz", "port": 8080}
>>> template = "http://{server}:{port}/images/{server}/index.html"
>>> template.format_map(data)
'http://xtz:8080/images/xtz/index.html'
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know `format_map`, seems the proper hammer to this nail =)

Comment: `format_map` is not really needed with a regular dict... `format(**d)` works just fine. `format_map` gives a cool solution when working with a `defaultdict` for example

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about use cases where it would make an inherent difference. That's a good example.

Comment: `format_map()` is a tiny bit faster than unpacking the dict into args though (about 3% on this particular example on my Windows Python 3.7).

Comment: Wow you actually benchmarked it, nice! It actually makes sense as it saves the unpacking and just relies on `O(1)` dict access...

Comment: Performance optimisation was kind of the paramount reason in my head, but I assumed it would be minimal (when you use every dict key in the template). If your data is large and you use only few keys, it will make a bigger difference.

Comment: This looks great. However, in the template .there is a space between the curly braces.

Comment: @PythonBeginner `input.replace(' ', '')`?